# Compute an average in a RDD and then filter this RDD based on the average in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I want to do something i feel very strange in Spark Streaming and i want to get some feedback on it.

I have a DStream of a tuple (String,Int). Let's say the string is an id and the integer a value.

So for a microbatch, I want to compute The average of the field Int, and base on this average i want to filter the same microbatch, for example field2 > average. So i wrote this code :

```
lineStreams
  .foreachRDD(
    rdd => {
      val totalElement = rdd.count()
      if(totalElement > 0) {
        val totalSum = rdd.map(elem => elem.apply(1).toInt).reduce(_ + _)
        val average = totalSum / totalElement
        rdd.foreach(
          elem => {
            if(elem.apply(1).toInt > average){
              println("Element is higher than average")
            }
          }
        )
      }
    })
```

But actually this code is not running, the first part of computation looks ok but not the test.
I know there is some dirty things in this code, but I just want to know if the logic is good.

Thanks for you advices !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lineStreams.transform { rdd => {
  val mean = rdd.values.map(_.toDouble).mean
  rdd.filter(_._2.toDouble > mean)
}}
```